# NSString initWithFormat returns "..."

Tags: iphone

I have just started developing for iPhone (I've been an Android developer for quite some time) and am having a problem with a very very...mundanely simple task: changing the text of a text label. I followed the Apple developer tutorial, but there is a problem with the initWithFormat method of NSString.

The issue is in this method:

```
-(IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }

    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", nameString];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}
```

When I run the project, whether there is a value in textField or not, the label is always set to Hello,...

When I change the last line of the method to:

```
self.label.text = self.userName;
```

or to:

```
self.label.text = nameString;
```

The label displays the value that SHOULD be inserted at the %@ in the initWithFormat call. Note: I have also tried using stringWithFormat and I get the same problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is too narrow. Assuming that it's in IB, open IB and make the label wider.

Comment: -_-, it's been a rough week. Thanks a bunch though!

Answer (score 0):

The ellipsis means that your string was too long for it's container. Try changing the length property to something bigger.